# Database Design attendance management system

Tags: database, architecture

I am developing an attendance system for employees and I have some doubts. 
By default an employee works from Monday to Friday (Holidays excluded). So, Do I need to store the attendance daily for each employee? Or is better to store only when the employee is absent and leave the application to calculate the difference between presence and absent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is purely philosophical, but I would tend to store the positive data fact, not the absence of a fact.  That being said, it really depends on the use-cases for your application.  If you are purely focused on absences, then you could store absences only.  But what do you do when an employee works a holiday?  Or a Saturday?  If you don't care to track this because these scenarios are impossible or irrelevant to your application, then just storing absences makes sense.  If they could be relevant, then you probably want both a "ScheduledDays" table and "EmployeeAttendedDays" table so that you can calculate everything you need.